# Chrome appears to report wrong line for error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm getting an error on line 975 ( this is what the console reports ), but when I look at the code it is clearly not 975.

Cannot read property E of undefined:

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is the screenshot showing the disparity for ...

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error line?

Comment: the console reports 975, why, I said that already, do you want a screen shot?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear: what do you think the actual error line should be? (trying to get at the disparity between what you think it should be + why and what the console reports) :)

Comment: screenshot added for your disparity

Comment: Yes; edited the question to help you clarify. What have you tried to solve the problem? Moving your code a line down...anything?

Comment: so you want me to validate the failure of Google on my own? and then what?

Comment: Not 'validate the failure of google', but rather help you actually solve your problem. If you haven't tried anything to fix it or see why it's reporting that line, we can't be of much help on here.

Comment: Presumably the error is related to one of the `this.E.xxx` references prior to that, it's the only `E` in the code. So somehow `this` has become undefined.

Comment: Have you used the debugger's `{}` tool to reformat the code? Maybe that confuses the line numbers.

Comment: @Barmar - no I have not I do not know what that is.

Comment: @user3293653: It's activated by default imho. It will pretty-print your code, and the debugger uses the line numbers of the pretty code not your minified/original one.

Comment: @Bergi That's not my experience, but maybe there's a hidden preference that controls it, and one of us has changed it from the default (I went through chrome://flags 6-9 months ago, I don't remember all the things I tweeked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible Chrome isn't reporting the specific line, but using line 975 as a reference to the segment of the code where property E doesn't seem to be found, thus line 975 could be in the middle of whatever code is problematic (some debuggers do this instead of reporting the first line they find a problem on - maybe Chrome's interpreter works like this, I don't know though, since I use Firefox for development instead). In that case, it would mean that `this` is what's undefined and there's your problem.

We'd have to see more to get a grip on why this would be happening since we can't determine what the context for `this` is from the screenshot. What is the expected value of `this` and if this is part of an object definition that you instantiate later, how do you instantiate it, as the context could matter for the value of `this`.